# How to give TextView a background colour in Android

Tags: android, background

I am trying to get my TextView to have white text on a black background. Here's what I have:

```
                <TextView
                   android:id="@+id/items_category"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:text="Category"
                   style="@style/Category" />
```

And in my styles.xml I have:

```
                <style name="Category">
                   <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
                   <item name="android:textSize">40sp</item>
                   <item name="android:colorBackground">#000000</item>
                </style>
```

The font size and colour is coming through correctly, but the background colour is not working. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
<item name="android:background">#000000</item>
```

You can also reference a color:

```
<item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
```

Or your own defined color:

```
<item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
```

Comment: That was it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If You give style in any view then it inherit all properties  which you define style..

Now if you want to change any properties then you have to just define it in view so it will overwrite that property for that view.

you can set background colour like below in your Textview so it will overwrite value of style background property :

```
<item name="android:background">#000000</item>
```